# How to check if dropdown has one value or none in jquery?

Tags: jquery

What I want to do is check if a drop down has one value or none and then make it read only?

```
if(){
 $('#dropdown').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}


<select class="dropdown" name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <option value="L6.5">L6.5</option>
   </select> 

<select class="dropdown" name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2"></select>


<select class="dropinput" name="dropdown3" id="dropdown3">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I need all top three dropdowns to be disabled

Comment: What do you mean by value? Could you give an example, maybe include some of your code.

Comment: so the above dropdown would be set to readonly because it only has one option/value

Comment: you can get value by using val(); http://api.jquery.com/val/#val, or use $('#select_id').html(); and check if there is any element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to HTML specs, the `select` tag in HTML doesn't have a readonly attribute, only a disabled attribute. Try this it will check for one or no option and `disable` it accordingly.

```
var $dd = $('#dropdown');
if($dd.find('option').length <= 1){
    $dd.prop('disabled', true);    
}
else{
    $dd.prop('disabled', false); 
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JRd9X/)**

Comment: sometimes the drop down can have options but they might be blank

Comment: this makes it disabled even if it has more than one value

Comment: Check my answer added the demo link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($('#dropdow').length < 2) {
  $('#yourcheck').attr('checked', true);
  $('#yourcheck').attr('readonly', true);
}
```