# Rails ajax execute call just first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm desiging a drop down menu with a lot of contents inside the menu and I want to load everything using an ajax get call on mouse enter.

This is coffeescript:

```
class @SecondaryMenu
  constructor: ->
    @element      = $('.nav-list li')
    @mainNav      = $('.nav-list')
    @secondaryNav = $('.nav-secondary')
    @bindEvents()

  bindEvents: ->
    @element.on 'mouseenter', (event) =>
      @openSecondaryMenu()
    @element.on 'mouseleave', (event) =>
      @closeSecondaryMenu()
    @secondaryNav.on 'mouseleave', (event) =>
      @closeSecondaryMenu()

  openSecondaryMenu: ->
    setTimeout =>
      @secondaryNav.stop(true).slideDown 200 if @hoveringMenu()
    , 300
```

I want to execute my ajax call just for the first "on mouse enter": when the content is loaded  I don't need another ajax call, because the content is already loaded.

I don't need the ajax call, I need a solution to avoid a call every time I hover the menu!

Answer (score 0):

To broadly answer your question, you'll need to be able to [determine if the dropdown has any `pre-existing values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034993/how-to-check-if-dropdown-has-one-value-or-none-in-jquery) before calling the `ajax`

Surely you could use `.length` to handle this?

```
class @SecondaryMenu
  constructor: ->
    @element      = $('.nav-list li')
    @mainNav      = $('.nav-list')
    @secondaryNav = $('.nav-secondary')
    @bindEvents()

  bindEvents: ->
    @element.on 'mouseenter', (event) =>
      @openSecondaryMenu() if @mainNav.find("option").length < 1
    @element.on 'mouseleave', (event) =>
      @closeSecondaryMenu()
    @secondaryNav.on 'mouseleave', (event) =>
      @closeSecondaryMenu()
```